# Override sublayout on a Screen or VerticalFieldManager

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am adding a VerticalFieldManager to a screen. I'm  painting a background image and to remove whitespace at the bottom of screen when user scrolls down im overriding sublayout in my verticalfieldmanager like so:

```
protected void sublayout( int maxWidth, int maxHeight ) {
    super.sublayout( maxWidth, maxHeight );
    setExtent(maxWidth,Constants.BACKGROUND_IMAGE.getHeight());  
}
```

This doesn't work -- white space appears at the bottom of the screen when the user scrolls down.  I thought overriding sublayout, using the same code, on the screen object would take precedence over the VerticalFieldManager, which is a child of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things to check. If, on your MainScreen, you're calling `super(VERTICAL_SCROLL | USE_ALL_WIDTH)` then your Screen's manager will be the one actually scrolling down, not the VFM you've customized. You may try overriding the paint() method of your VFM and do something as such:

```
protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
    graphics.drawBitmap(0, getVerticalScroll(), bg.getWidth(), bg.getHeight(), bg, 0, 0);
    super.paint(graphics);
}
```

Which should make your background "move" with the scroll.

Comment: Shouldnt Super be called first? In this case it would override the drawBitmap?

Comment: It's a background, so you want to draw it first, and then let everything else draw on top (by calling `super()` after).